# In SimpleAdapter duplicates one row item click configurations in Android

Tags: android

I am using SimpleAdapter to fill a ListView with Items. Every row represent more than one buttons and when user lick on one button of row must be hide or show other buttons of the same row or change the same button color. But I am scrolling the list after a any row the ListView duplicates my clicks, for example if I am click in the position 2 and change button color and enable the same position other buttons, and then scroll list to n position up or down (n = number of rows shown in display), the I have seen that in the n+1 hapens same events.
Please help, I think that I must extend SimpleAdapter and override getView() method, but not now how.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    int my_layout;
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> map;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.my_layout = resource;
        this.context = context;
        map = data;         
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final LinearLayout view;
        final Button btnConnect;
        Button b1;
        Button b2;
        ImageView img;

        if (null == convertView) {
            view = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this.context, 
                R.layout.list_item_meeting, null);
            convertView = view;                         
        } else {
            view = (LinearLayout) convertView;             
        }   

            btnConnect = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnJoinMeeting);                
    b1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        b2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgConnetionStatus);    


            btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //RelativeLayout parent = ((RelativeLayout)btnConnect.getParent());
                    Button b1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
                    Button b2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
                    ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgConnetionStatus);

                    if((btnConnect.getText().toString()).equals("Join meeting")){
                        btnConnect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bd0000"));                     
                        btnConnect.setText("Leave meeting");
                        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        btnConnect.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#adc627"));
                        btnConnect.setText("Join meeting");
                        b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }                               
                }
            });

            return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set id to each row, and save it in one array,like integer and when you click on one row you must change the value of that, and in setting color and anything you must check the value of that row,if 0 then set default and if 1 then so what you want:
my idea is create int[] with length of that is size of your list,

Comment: I was set buttons click setting in the data (ArrayList) of SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even understand what you are doing ??You are putting alot of code in both if and else.What is the need of it??better keep that code outside the if else portion.Clean the mess up then only people will understand your code....
And another thing,why are you finding the same view again and again??better keep the variable as global and assign it once.

by the way...here is how i setup my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
           v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_songs, parent, false);

        }
        SongDetails sng = _data.get(position);
        TextView SongView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Song);
        TextView TimeView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        TextView ArtistView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        SongView.setText(sng.getSong());
       TimeView.setText(sng.getTime()); 
        ArtistView.setText(sng.getArtist());
         return v;
    }
```

Comment: I was not need to set simple values to item fields, what you read, I can do the same thing in the binder, but I want to set click listener e.t..